# Microsoft Exchange Server: This Property was requested, but it was not returned by server (EWS)

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to get the value of a bool property Exchange Web Service "IsMeeting" using C#. I define the following properties in PropertySet object:

```
PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject,
                                          AppointmentSchema.AppointmentState,
                                          AppointmentSchema.Start,
                                          AppointmentSchema.End,
                                          AppointmentSchema.Organizer,
                                          AppointmentSchema.IsMeeting,
                                          AppointmentSchema.IsCancelled,
                                          AppointmentSchema.IsRecurring,
                                          AppointmentSchema.IsAllDayEvent,
                                          AppointmentSchema.LegacyFreeBusyStatus,
                                          ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime,
                                          AppointmentSchema.TimeZone,
                                          AppointmentSchema.MeetingRequestWasSent,
                                          AppointmentSchema.ICalUid,
                                          ItemSchema.Id);
```

However, when trying to get properties:

```
foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(a.IsMeeting.ToString());
            }
```

an exception occurs "ServiceObjectPropertyException". This Property was requested, but it was not returned by server.
A similar problem was with the IsCancelled property. Adding the AppointmentState property to the PropertySet helped.
With the IsMeeting property, there are no solution ideas. I will be glad if someone can tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only a subset of properties are returned by FindItems because of performance reasons. If you really want that property then you need to make and additional GetItem (or Bind) request on the Item. If your using the EWS Managed API you can do that with LoadPropertiesForItems see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.loadpropertiesforitems?view=exchange-ews-api&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-10145

You should also be able to just use AppointmentState which should return 0x0001 for a Meeting

Comment: Glen Scales thanks for you answer. 
I guess I'm already making such a request this way:
`appointments = CalendarFolder.Bind(service,targetFolder[i].Id,BasePropertySet.IdOnly).FindAppointments(cView); service.LoadPropertiesForItems(from Item item in appointments select item, propertySet);`

If you need additional code used by me to solve the issue, I am ready to provide

Comment: I tried to use the AppointmentState property to get the meeting attribute, but I got a similar error(

Comment: something doesn't sound correct then, those properties are calculated from the underlying meeting properties. The only thing I can think of is its a badly migrated data, what happens on newly created appointment? is this for a user or is it a Meeting Room ?

Comment: I'm trying to get meetings of multiple users by connecting to a technical mailbox that has read rights using a loop. I still don't know what the problem was. There may be network problems. After I added retry count and retry delay after failed requests, my problem was solved. Glen thank you for your help.